# Getting an error I don't understand while trying to scrape Google for links

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, mechanize-python

I'm very new to Python so I apologize if this is an easy question, I'm trying to write a web scraper to scrape Google for all relevant links pertaining to networking, using BeautifulSoup, and Mechanize.

While scrapping I'm getting an error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 30, in <module>
    test.find_soup()
  File "scrape.py", line 23, in find_soup
    data = BS(self._launch()).read()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I don't understand what's going on would someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS
import mechanize
import urlparse


class Initialize(object):

    def __init__(self, url, search):
        self.url = url
        self.search = search

    def _launch(self):
        search = mechanize.Browser()
        search.set_handle_robots(False)
        search.set_handle_equiv(False)
        search.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        search.open(self.url)
        search.select_form(name="f")
        search.form["q"] = self.search
        return search.submit()

    def find_soup(self):
        data = BS(self._launch()).read()
        i = 0
        for link in data.select(".r a"):
            return "Relevant link [{}]: {}".format(i+1,
                                                   urlparse.urlparse(link["href"]).query["q"][0])

test = Initialize("https://google.com", "networking")
test.find_soup()
```

Comment: You should be using bs4 and the Beautifulsoup object does not have a .read attribute  `BS(self._launch()).read()` so `.read()` is giving you the error as `read` is `None`.

Comment: Try printing out some things to figure out which value is `None`. It's something you're trying to call on that line, so it could be `BS`, `self._launch`, or `BS(self._launch()).read`. Print each out and figure out which one is `None`.

Comment: Change to  `BS(self._launch().read())` so you call read on `search.submit()` but you have more errors on the way

Comment: @smarx I did that and was able to figure out how to get one link, thank you

Comment: @PythonicPenguin, you have more errors in your code, apart from that `return` ends your loop so you would at best only ever get one link, what you want is `yield` and to loop over `test.find_soup()`